# Flask Python REST API set optional JSON param when receiving POST

Tags: python, json, api, rest, flask

I'm building a REST API with Flask which add a photo to a database. The database is abstracted in PhotoModel Class. The API receives a JSON formated HTTP POST which contain the picture in a bin string an the name, all the other parameters are optional.

How to construct "photo" object if some param aren't present in the JSON posted?
On the database Model (PhotoModel) I have specify only two compulsory items, so the logic to only take into account params present in the JSON should be in the function bellow.

```
def add_photo():
"""Add photo to database"""
if request.method == 'POST' and request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
    photo = PhotoModel(
        name = request.json['name'],
        device_version = request.json['device_version'],
        date = request.json['date'],
        picture = request.json['picture'],
        comment = request.json['comment']
    )
    try:
        photo.put()
        return "200"
    except CapabilityDisabledError:
        return "500 DB read-only"
else:
    return "415 Unsupported Media Type"
```

I can't figure out how to do it, any pointer would help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [peewee](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-api.html) it comes with a RESTful API in JSON. It's also an light ORM engine.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered JSON Schema and it works fantastic to validate JSON requests.

Create a decorator which you can use for all views:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

from jsonschema import validate as jsonschema_validate

def validate(schema):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            # Validate request Content Type
            if request.json is None:
                raise ValidationError("Content Type must be JSON")
            # Validate document
            jsonschema_validate(request.json, schema)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator
```

Use decorator for your views:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@validate(schema)
def insert_document():
    # now your request.json object is validated against the specified schema
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = request.get_json() #You can use any method here. 

#Below the required parameters outside the try

email=data['email']
role=data['role']
try:
   #Here are the optional json parameters inside a try
   firstname = data['firstname']
   lastname = data['lastname']
except KeyError:
   #Here handle the exception, maybe parse some default values. 
   pass
```

Comment: This won't parse parameters that come after the null parameter.